# Is it possible to get values for <options> from an endpoint that sends back json response using axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

So, I have this endpoint: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/materials
that would return this json response:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "uuid": "05a36470-d0a0-11e7-91b4-ff3d7d9f961a",
        "title": "Apple",
        "viewing_time": 15,
        "description": "",
        "organization_id": null,
        "created_at": "2017-11-24 06:45:36",
        "updated_at": "2017-11-24 06:45:36",
        "deleted_at": null
    },


    {
        "uuid": "2048f730-bfa0-11e7-95fb-6dceb95ba437",
        "title": "Banana",
        "viewing_time": 15,
        "description": "It's a fruit",
        "organization_id": null,
        "created_at": "2017-11-02 15:33:31",
        "updated_at": "2017-11-02 15:33:31",
        "deleted_at": null
    },


    {
        "uuid": "3b6a1020-d0a0-11e7-b6bb-d77fc76d610b",
        "title": "Strawberry",
        "viewing_time": 15,
        "description": "",
        "organization_id": null,
        "created_at": "2017-11-24 06:47:06",
        "updated_at": "2017-11-24 06:47:06",
        "deleted_at": null,
    },
```

I want to pick all the titles and make them options.
and this is my function where axios is called:

```
materialList = () => {
    var token = localStorage.getItem('jwt');
    var apiBaseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/materials";

    var config = {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': "bearer " + token,
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      withCredentials: false
    }

    axios.get(apiBaseUrl, config)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);

  })
  .catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
  });
  }
```

and this is where I want the titles (Apple, Banana and Strawberry) to appear:

```
            <Form.Input list='material' placeholder='Material' name="material_id" id="material_id" onChange={this.onChange}/>
            <datalist id='material_id'>
                <option value=/** What do I put here **/ />

            </datalist>
```

I have used axios when submitting a post request to the api, but can I trigger an axios get request as soon as the page loads, so that I can get the title I needed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a state variable as shown below in your component.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        options: []
    }
}
```

Now, you can use **componentDidMount()** to get those values from the API as shown below.

```
componentDidMount() {
 const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt');

 const apiBaseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/materials";

 const config = {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': "bearer " + token,
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
 }

 axios.get(apiBaseUrl, config)
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState({
      options: response.data
    })
   })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
   });
}
```

Now you can use that state variable to show in the option.

```
render() {
 const { options } = this.state;

 return(
  <Form.Input list='material' placeholder='Material' name="material_id" id="material_id" onChange={this.onChange}>
   {options.map((item, index) => <option key={index} value={item.uuid}>{item.title}</option>)}
  </Form.Input>
 )
}
```

Comment: but now it says, 
TypeError: options.map is not a function

Comment: Use it like this: `{options && options.map((item, index) => <option key={index} value={item.uuid}>{item.title}</option>)}`

Comment: And, you can use html **Select** tag rather than Form.Input

Comment: First check what are you getting in response ? that error is coming because there is no data in the options, so check if you are getting the response properly from the axios

Comment: And I have set options to response.data depending on the json response which you have provided. So check if that is correct

Answer (score 1):

First, add an `options` array to your state.

Next, in your axios function:

```
axios.get(apiBaseUrl, config)
.then(response => {
    this.setState({
        options: response.data.map(item => item.title),
    });
})
```

Finally, in your UI component (assuming you've made the `options` from earlier available as a variable of the same name):

```
const optionList = options.map(option => <option value={option} />)

render() {
    return (
        // Other JSX here..
        <datalist id='material_id'>
           {optionList}
        </datalist>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the `jsx` code you post is what inside your component render function.

If you required data from external source and want to make a http request to get these data whenever the component is mounted. What you might want to do is to get the data inside `componentDidMount`, save it to your state, and use it inside your render function, an example can be found below:

```
class YourComponent {
    // Use componentDidMount to get the data via axios
    componentDidMount() {
        // ... Your code to prepare the axios call

        /* 
         * Use arrow function to keep refer to React component `this`
         * and sae the response data to the component state
         */
        axios.get(apiBaseUrl, config)
          .then(
             response => this.setState({options: response.data})
          )
          .catch(function (error) {
             // handle the error here
          });
    }

    render() {
        // Options will have the same format as your response data
        const { options } = this.state;

        return (<datalist id='material_id'>
            {options.map(option =>  
               <option value={/* can be any attribute you want from the result object, like id, title, ..etc*/}>
                 {option.title}
               </option>)}
        </datalist>);
    }
}
```

Comment: but now it says 
TypeError: options.map is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the triggering of the API request when the page will load: 
Make yourself familiar with the React lifecycle methods. 
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

In this case I would go for the componentDidMount() method:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.materialList();
}
```

If you do not plan to use redux to save the state, you need will probably need to call a setState() here in order to save the result of your request in your component's state (like Nico described).